# Configure SilkPerformer to work with Fiddler

Tags: http, load-testing, sniffing

Does anyone know how to capture a Silk Performer HTTP request, using Fiddler?

We can't seem to capture this information no matter what we try (it seems like it ignores all proxy settings).